# Error during share via facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook

i want to share text Via Facebook so followed this link http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/457153/How-to-integrate-Facebook-Twitter-Linkedin-in-Andr, but getting error in the place of "FACEBOOK" as facebook cannot b solved or not a field..

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);


    // Add it to Library
    final SocialAuthAdapter adapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());
    adapter.addProvider(Provider.FACEBOOK, R.drawable.facebook);
    adapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());

    ListView lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);  

    lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, adapter));
    adapter.enable(share);
```

Comment: Try Facebook mFacebook = new Facebook("your_app_id");

Comment: I thing you forget to add sharing permissions.

Comment: For sharing text to facebook u need to use Facebook SDK, did u know that?

Comment: i included ur code but m getting Facebook should be created as class.@AliImran

Comment: @Mahdi Giveie, yes using Facebook SDK only i had done the coding

Comment: @user1897069 If my answer is helping you then please accept it.

Comment: Hi , I think you have not added the socialauth library correctly. I suppose you have downloaded the sdk from http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/ . Check the examples given in sdk. If still face issue you can mail to support email id(labs@3pillarglobal.com) given on website for instant help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the imports... You are importing a wrong Provider.
You need to remove `java.security.Provider` or anyother import for Provider. and then re-import the right Provider that is from the library u added.

Comment: now getting error in provider as "provider cannot be resolved" @Faizan

Comment: Import the provider from the facebook or whatever social library u added